# How to toggle between two custom fields in WordPress woocommerce 'WC Product Field Group' plugin?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a full suit tailoring WordPress website and it using woocommerce plugin. I need 2 custom field groups to show in single-product page.

1. Custom Measurements (Precise)
   In this method the client has to measure and enter every single data like height weight etc.
2. Standard Sizes (Quick)
   This is world standard sizes. Small, Medium,Large,etc.

I've created 2 custom field groups and they are visible only with 'Product Category name'

I need to toggle between these 2 field groups when a client selects their interested measuring method 1 or 2.

I don't have good knowledge in PHP so if its possible I prefer some easy method to do that.

[image]

Comment: Hi Gimhana Jayasekara, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins off-topic so you might notice some down-votes. Nevertheless, I hope someone can give you a good answer. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt Thank you so much for not removing my post. I've found a solution and put it here. Hope that may help someone. I didn't have anyone to ask. I searched for 2 days and then I decide to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do that. Its all in **WC Fields Factory** plugin. Not a single line of PHP coding is required.
I'll put full guideline to follow.

1. Install the plugin
   [image: WC Fields Factory plugin]
2. Activate the plugin
3. Go to **Fields Factory** tab in left sidebar of WordPress dashboard.
   [image: Fields Factory dashboard]
4. Add new WC field group
   [image]
5. Add all the input element types you need (Labels, Selects, texts, etc)
6. Add the Conditions rule set to show the input fields
   [image: Condition Rules]
7. Save changes and update
8. then go to the top element you added.
9. Select the field rules tab
   [image: field rules tab]
10. Give the show hide rules according to the selection
    [image: Rules for custom measurements]
    [image: Rules for standard measurements]
11. And you are good to go. Hope this helps anyone who struggled like me.